# How to extract json data from a Promise.all in node.js

Tags: node.js, promise

**This works fine**

```
esi_requests.fetch('character_info', {character_id: character_id})
  .then( results => results.json() )
  .then( results => {
    console.log(results)
  })
```

**But how do I get the same information from 2 promises with a Promise.all?**

```
  Promise.all([
    esi_requests.fetch('character_info', {character_id: character_id}),
    esi_requests.fetch('character_info', {character_id: member_id})
  ])
  .then( results=> {
    // what do I do here to translate the response-body from both requests to json?
  })
  .then( results => {
    console.log(results)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it before you have the results.  Performance is actually quite a bit better if you do.  You don't have to wait for all the requests to finish before you start .json'ing them.

e.g.:

```
 Promise.all([
    esi_requests.fetch('character_info', {character_id: character_id}).then(res => res.json()),
    esi_requests.fetch('character_info', {character_id: member_id}).then(res => res.json())
  ])
  .then( results => {
    console.log(results)
  })
```

What you probably actually want is a function that sets this up for you.

```
const example = id => esi_requests.fetch('character_info', {character_id: id}).then(res => res.json());

Promise.all([character_id, member_id].map(example))
  .then( results => {
    console.log(results);
  })
```